# MATLAB: adding contour lines to points

Tags: matlab

(Hi, I new to this site and matlab so If something seems dodgy I do apologize.)

I am given this question:
[image]

So far my code looks like this:

```
x = [2,-3,0];
y = [3,3,-2];
figure
plot(x,y,'*')
```

Now, how could I add contour lines(with each different sizes to show different charge strength) to each of these points?

Comment: You have to define your potential field and use the `contour` function.

Comment: @Ratbert how do I define it?